# Put variable int option select

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to select an Select Option throuh jQuery with a PHP variable.

HTML

```
<div id="dom-target">
<?php 
    $output = $user->distritos;
    echo htmlspecialchars($output);
?>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
    var div = document.getElementById("dom-target");
    var myData = div.textContent;
    jQuery('select[name="country"]').find('option:contains(" + myData + ")').attr("selected",true);    
</script>
```

But won't change, only if I replace `option:contains(" + myData + ")` by text, for example `option:contains("123")` it will select option with text "123"

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are concatenating a string inside of `find()`. Consider these three parts of the string:

1. `option:contains("`
2. the value of `myData`
3. `")`

To build such a string, you'll need to close the single quote after the first part, append `myData`, and open the single quote again for the third part.

Otherwise, you're selecting an `<option>` that contains the string " + myData + ".

```js
var $div = jQuery("#dom-target"),
    myData = $div.text();

jQuery('select').find('option:contains("' + myData + '")').prop("selected", true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="dom-target">foo</div>

<select>
  <option>test</option>
  <option>option 2</option>
  <option>foo</option>
  <option>bar</option>
</select>
```